# Rails - Gem to letterize money?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to letterize a money data just like in cheque.

So if I have `$ 85700`, I need to letterize it into `Eighty Five Thousand Seven Hundred Dollars` or something like that.

Is there gem that helps us create that?

I have been searching for a while but can't seem to get the right search query.

[EDIT]

Using the gem mentioned below, it converts the number into words. But the decimal point is called "hundredths". So, I replace it with "cents":

```
words = digit.to_f.to_words
words["hundredths"] = "cents"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it will helps you:

[Spelling Out Numbers](http://www.jackiejohnston.us/blog/ruby-spelling-out-numbers/)

Or use following gem:

[numbers_and_words](https://github.com/kslazarev/numbers_and_words)

Comment: Do you have an idea on how to use the `numbers_and_words` gem? I put it into Gemfile, install it and set `require 'numbers_and_words'` in my helper, but `.to_words` still return undefined method.

Comment: Nevermind, It's because the data I got from Postgres is `BigDecimal`, by converting it to float (`to_f`), I can make it into words.